# Selenium waitForPopup with dynamic windowId?

Tags: selenium

When using Selenium how can I wait for a popup window if its id is dynamically generated?
For example:

```
selenium.click("link=mylink");
selenium.waitForPopUp("popup072815372337691199");
```

Obviously I cannot hardcode the window id in my source code. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

It would obviously be best to have a consistent or fully predictable window name, however if this is not possible you could try using the `getAllWindowNames` command to wait until the number of windows increments. If the name of the window is somewhat predictable (like a consistent prefix) you could then find out the full name of the new window before using `waitForPopup` or `selectWindow`.

Comment: I wanted to say the same thing, but a popup is not a window isn't it? So getAllWindow would not get it... Or if it would then you could use a regex to search for it. But that's the whole point that you don't know the id that you are looking for.

So you could use something like :popup/d+

Comment: With getAllWindowNames() or getAllWindowIds() it is possible to retrieve the popup window's name. The problem is that right after selenium.click() these methods don't find the popup. I would have to wait for "some" seconds until the popup window is found. So I have the same problem that I don't know the time to wait until I get a reliable result.

Comment: The idea with the regex is a good one, but it will only work for the "popupXXX" pattern. What if I have no idea at all how the windowId of the popup will look like?

Comment: `waitForPopup` is for actual windows. If you're using Selenium RC then you can 'wait' until the window exists by having a loop continuously evaluating the result of `getAllWindowNames`. You can probably even do this in Selenium IDE by making clever use of the `waitForCondition` command.

Comment: Your welcome. Might be worth sharing your solution as an answer to your own question - to help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

do it this way....

```
    'String href = selenium.getAttribute("link=myLink@herf");
     selenium.openWindow(href, "myWindow");
     selenium.selectWindow("myWindow");
     selenium.click(...);
     // do whatever
     selenium.selectWindow(null); // go back to the previous window'
```